# Is the memory empty after power off ubuntu

Tags: ram

I am learning the fundamentals of CS and confused about the main memory.

I learned that BIOS reside on mainboard and  linux was install in mass storage disk(such as HDD)

After I firstly installed ubuntu, and power off before clear up all the caches.

Now, on the status of power-off,

Is the main-memory is empty? Does any utilities accessories or anything should be installed to the memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you turn off your machine, power (or refresh cycles) that are needed to allow RAM to keep its contents are gone so it will soon lose it's contents and become meaningless (or random).

In theory RAM can survive up to ~15 seconds after power is cut (depends on a lot of factors, hardware & esp. temperature -- you can super-cool chips to prolong the loss up beyond 15 mins if you're lucky) - but you need physical access to the machine of course to take advantage of this.

Yes once power is cut, memory will lose contents, but it's not instantaneous, but we can usually ignore these extreme cold-hacks.

ROM is read-only memory, and doesn't need power to keep it's value.

BIOS is either stored in ROM, EPROM (erasable programming ROM used on really old hardware) or flash-memory (allowing you to change its contents with programs for update purposes) - none of these require power, so values don't get lost with power.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack mentions that it can take up to 90 minutes for all data to fade from RAM under regular conditions, or even weeks if the module is cooled down. This fading is also a steady process where more and more cells gradually lose their value over time, so the percentage of corrupted data will increase slowly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your ram is completely empty when you turn off the power.
Any object you want to survive a reboot shouldn't be kept in memory.